# Does HttpClient.GetAsync() create a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Does `HttpClient.GetAsync()` create a new thread? My understanding is that it doesn't; that it instead makes a request against an OS-level networking system, which is itself running on a new thread already.

However, some questions and comments have emerged in my office that are challenging this idea.

Ultimately, the question comes down to this; "Is it possible to run a WPF application, and asynchronously `await` an HTTP request, without blocking the UI thread and without creating a new thread?"

Corollary question; when we make a `HttpClient.GetAsync()` request, how does the method "know" it's completed? By what mechanism is `.Result` populated?

We have experience writing this kind of functionality, but we're unsure how to actually find information relating to this at a lower level.

Comment: Take a look at this: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: What questions and comments have emerged to challenge the idea? What aspect of "create a new thread" are you worried about? Have you used `async`/`await` according to normal patterns and found that the UI thread is blocking or that you're seeing new threads get spun up?

Comment: There was a general discussion about the nature of `async`/`await`, and a discussion regarding whether they could be used for parallelism. There's potentially some appetite at my place of work to multithread some processing jobs.

Comment: If you start a number of tasks and then do a series of awaits after you have started them then you have introduced parallelism. It seems to me that what you're asking in this question doesn't get you to the result you're looking for.

Comment: @Enigmativity This question arose out of that discussion and is, by and large, purely academic :)

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic - Then you've posted this on the wrong site.

Comment: Old but gold video about [async IO by Jeffrey Richter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9UTfymRZXU)

Comment: @Enigmativity - Can I ask why? Which site would you suggest?

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic - If you're asking a practical problem then ask here. If it's theoretical then you should post on the https://cs.stackexchange.com/ site.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I don't believe that's an appropriate place for this question. I feel this question fits well into [SO topic guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 

CS-SE would not be appropriate. In fact, they specify that asking "how does x work?" isn't appropriate [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). My question is regarding a _"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_. Just because we aren't putting this information into practice today doesn't mean the question is not practical. See also; SO FAQ on homework questions.

Answer (score 2):

> Corollary question; when we make a HttpClient.GetAsync() request, how does the method "know" it's completed? By what mechanism is .Result populated?

Network communication uses non-blocking sockets and triggers events when new packets come in. Those events are processed "somewhere" into proper TCP packets and then data is streamed (through a `Stream`) back up the chain. You can then read the response either from the stream or with various convenience methods (like `ReadAsStringAsync` which basically handle reading the stream for you).

TLDR: Network communication is event based, and event triggers trigger further events down the line until you get chunks of data one at a time.

> Does HttpClient.GetAsync() create a new thread?

No, but it does use a thread pool thread for the tiny amount of computation necessary to assemble the network packets into something a `Stream` can iterate over.

Comment: "somewhere" being an IO Completion Port callback, which is usually handled by a threadpool thread as mentioned.

Comment: How does this answer the question `Is it possible to run a WPF application, and asynchronously await an HTTP request, without blocking the UI thread and without creating a new thread?`

Comment: It doesn’t, obviously. If you need help answering that, feel free to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to how async/await works, each `await` is basically syntactic sugar for a state machine that gets called several times, from the same thread, which is why you should always `await` any `async` code, and not call `.Result` until you are absolutely sure the code has been executed.

To answer your actual question, yes, that's the whole point of async/await.  Why do you care if another thread is running?  Even if there was 1 thread running the UI and 1 thread running the background tasks (or 100), would it make a difference to you?  The async/await stuff is open source, you can find out yourself how it works.

As [Theodor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11178549/theodor-zoulias) points out, [Steven Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com) is your goto resource for anything async/await related.

Comment: It's possible the OP is really more interested in knowing whether the continuation of the task is going to run on a separate thread.

Comment: "There is no thread" it doesn't need a second thread to be running anywhere, it can be fully handled by a single-threaded application.

Comment: How does this answer the question `Is it possible to run a WPF application, and asynchronously await an HTTP request, without blocking the UI thread and without creating a new thread?`

Comment: I could have just answered "Yes" and that would have answered the question.  The OP misunderstands async/await, which my answer helps with.

Answer (score -4):

To answer your *actual* question:

> Is it possible to run a WPF application, and asynchronously await an HTTP request, without blocking the UI thread and without creating a new thread?

Your issue is not with HttpClient, but might be with the way Winforms and WPF process events.  While you may call your Event via `async void`.  The event is not actually Asynchronous nor part of a Task chain.  The code is run on the UI thread which causes events to block.  You can read more about how the Synchronization Context affect these types of applications work in the following links (much too lengthy  to post here).

TLDL Either you have an issue with async avoid, or the Default Syncronization Context in WPF which calls Post basically calls Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (which might start a new thread for the async call depending on how it's configured and how you've used `ConfigureAwait()`).

[Microsoft - ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

> The same goes for Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). It has its own SynchronizationContext-derived type with a Post override that similarly “marshals” a delegate to the UI thread (via Dispatcher.BeginInvoke), in this case managed by a WPF Dispatcher rather than a Windows Forms Control.

[Microsoft - Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

[Microsoft - Single Threaded Application with Long Running Calculation Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/main/Threading/SingleThreadedApplication)

[Async and Async Void Event Handling in WPF](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Apr/22/Async-and-Async-Void-Event-Handling-in-WPF)